# redeclaration of a functoin as int K&R 6.3

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

In chapter 6.3 of K&R the function getword() is defined like this:

```
int getword(char *word, int lim)
{
    int c, getch(void);
    void ungetch(int);
    char *w = words;

    while(isspace(c=getch()))
        ;
        if(c!= EOF)
            *w++; = c;
        if(isalpha(c)) {
            *w = '\0';
            return c;
        }

        for(;--lim > 0; w++)
            if(!isalnum(*w)getch()){
                ungetch(*w);
                break;
            }
        *w = '\0';
        return word[0];
}
```

I don't understand the syntax of the line

**int c, getch(void);**

it is the first time I'm seeing this. Why is it declaring a function as int? Shouldn't be enough to insert prototypes of functions before calling them?

Comment: The original code from K&R is complete trash, one does not write modern C programs like this. Nothing to learn here except bad habits. I'd strongly recommend getting a better book.

Comment: @Lundin Can you please recommend some modern C books for beginner and Advanced level.

Comment: Neither the K&R book nor the code fragment in question is "complete trash".  @Lundin has an unreasonable bias here.

Comment: @EsmaeelE Stack Overflow has a [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @SteveSummit 1)There is never a reason to declare prototypes inside functions, 2) particularly not on the same line as variables. 3) Assignment inside control statements are bad practice. 4) Mixing ++ together with assignment is bad practice. 5) Multiple return or break jumping here and there is unreadable. 6) There is no reason to use `lim` as iterator instead of `(i=0; i<lim; i++)` as done in sane code. 7)`*w = '\0';` is code repetition. 7 problems in some 15 LoC. Summary: complete trash.

Comment: @Lundin Not gonna get into a back-and-forth here, and some of your points are fair, but if by(3) you mean putting `c = getch()` inside the controlling expression of a `while()`, and if by (4) you mean `*w++ = c`, both of those are absolutely idiomatic C, and they have significant benefits beyond parsimony, so they're definitely not problems; anyone who has problems with them either needs to learn the idioms and understand their benefits, or abandon C.

Comment: @SteveSummit Definitely not gonna debate "Yoda conditions". Beating the dead horse. But feel free to point out a mainstream compiler which doesn't warn against assignment inside conditions.

Comment: @Lundin I know of no mainstream compiler that will warn about `while(isspace(c=getch()))`, or the more conventional `while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`.

Answer (score 4):

Think of the line

```
int c, getch(void);
```

as being equivalent to

```
int c;
int getch(void);
```

That is, it's a declaration of an `int` variable named `c`, followed by a prototype for a function named `getch` taking no arguments and returning `int`.

As this example shows, there's no hard line between "declarations" and "function prototypes" in C.  A function prototype is merely a declaration, that declares a function type, that includes the types of its arguments.

It's mildly unusual, but not at all wrong, to declare a function prototype with local scope like this.  Normally, a function prototype is declared "at the top" of a source file, with global scope, outside of any function.  (In fact, normally, function prototypes are declared in header files.)

> Why is it declaring a function as int?

Well, because the `getch` function *does* return `int`.

> Shouldn't be enough to insert prototypes of functions before calling them?

Yes, and that's exactly what this like is doing -- this line does contain a function prototype, which declares the `getch` function before calling it.

The bottom line is that every function declaration in C is "external", whether it appears inside or outside a function, whether it contains the storage-class specifier `extern` or not.

Comment: I've never seen a prototype declared within a function but always outside

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci It's mildly unusual, but not at all wrong.

Comment: It is very wrong to declare function prototypes at local scope, period.

Comment: @Lundin "Very wrong"? No, I think that's too strong.